# How to create a TextView with title and background shape

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, textview

I am looking to create TextViews like the following, but have had no luck so far:

[TextViews with titles and background shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v9u4.jpg)

Is this possible with a TextView or is something like a CardView needed?

So far I have created two TextViews, one being the title and the other the value that needs to be displayed. However, there must be a better solution, and I don't know how to create the box surrounding the TextViews.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There you go

`activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        tools:style="@style/CardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Current Training Maxes"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    tools:style="@style/CardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#5E9EA0"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="Bench"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="62.5"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    tools:style="@style/CardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#5E9EA0"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="Squat"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="70.0"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    tools:style="@style/CardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#5E9EA0"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="Deadlift"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="102.5"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    tools:style="@style/CardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#5E9EA0"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="OHP"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="45.5"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Tip

- don't forget to add `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'` to your `build.gradle`
- read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Thank you so much!